# Question on a set describing transitive binary relation?

Tags: math, data-structures, set, structure

The image below shows a set that is supposed to describe a binary transitive relation:

[image]

That first arrow notation looks good at first until I saw the d node. I thought that since d cannot reach b (or any other node, yet it connects to c), it cannot be transitive?

A little bit of clarification would be great

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here try posting on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/. Theoretical CS questions aren't Stack Overflow's bailiwick.

Comment: Gotcha, I realized I might have a better time posting on Math.StackExchange but it doesn't allow you to post a question unless you wait 40 minutes unfortunately which is quite annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first panel is fine, i.e., it *is* transitive. Transtivity does not require `d` has a (directed) path to `b` in this case. Transitivity, by definition, requires "if there are `x` and `y` such that `d → x` and `x → y`, then it must be `d → y`". Since `c` (which potentially play the role of `x` here) does not go to anywhere, as for a chain of arrows that starts from `d`, there is no condition that needs to be satisfied (i.e., vacuously true, when starting from `d`).

Comment: Gotcha, so you're essentially saying that d does not have access to enough directed edges to even consider the possibility of it being transitive or non-transitive, therefore it shouldn't be included in the entire question of whether or not the set is in itself transitive? (I tend to need the ELI5 version of explainations)

Comment: @CaliCrunch That's correct!